# ShareThis plugin wordpress Magento FishPig remove @sharethis mention and replace

Tags: wordpress, magento, plugins, sharethis, fishpig

```
<span class='st_twitter_hcount' st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' st_via='twittername' displayText='twitter'></span>
```

I am using the above code and was wondering if anyone has ran into this using FishPig, Magento,  wordpress, and Share This plugin.  I simply cannot get the @share this replacecd with my twittername.  I don't see a db table for this value either...maybe someone would have an idea.

Thanks,
John

Comment: I wish it worked that way, I am getting ready to ditch share this, there has got to be some conflict..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I solved this issue, I used addthis instead of ShareThis, and I am super happy and got it to work instantly. So if someone else has this issue I would use addthis.

Answer (score 0):

You should just need to change the "st_via" parameter on the span to your Twitter username (without the "@").